# Como "darse de baja" de un evento (Unsubscribe) - Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, eventos

Estoy aprendiendo sobre la `"anulación" / "darse de baja"` de eventos (`Unsubscribe`) y tengo dos dudas.

Este ejemplo me parece bastante sencillo:

```
void BindHandlers()
{
forgotPassword.Click+= ForgotPassword_Click;
}
```

.

```
void ForgotPassword_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
StartActivity (typeof(ForgotPasswordActivity));
}
```

.

```
void UnBindHandlers()
{
loginButton.Click-= LoginButton_Click;
forgotPassword.Click-= ForgotPassword_Click;
}
```

Duda:

> 1. Ese seria el proceso completo? El `UnBindHandlers();` basta para darse de baja y evitar un posible leak?

Comment: Tenes que desuscribirte en el evento que se acciona cuando desaparece la vista, y no hay metodos voids innecesarios de dos lineas, mientras menos lineas tenga un metodo mejor, asi es mas facil de mantener.

Comment: Entiendo, pero el punto es: Como me des-suscribo? Estoy teniendo problemas para entender esa parte. Gracias.

Comment: Icono = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.IconoBuscar);
                Icono.Click -= BtnGoBusqueda;   // Es esto suficiente?

Comment: con el ejemplo que tenes te das de baja, solo resta saber donde lo usas nada mas. Si se ejecuta cuando la ventana se va, como lo haces

Comment: Lo ejecuto en el evento OnPause(). Crees que esta correcto ahi?